# Converting int value to String without using toString and parseInt method

Tags: java, interview-questions, reinventing-the-wheel

I am studying about the converting int to string and string to int without using `toString` and `parseInt` method. I already made methods. However, I don't believe that my way of doing was the best. I would like to improve these function.

For example, the first converts from `String` to `int`:

```
public static int StringToint(String number)
        int eachnumber = 0;
    int intConvert = 48;
    int reVal = 0;
    int index;
    int maxlen =number.length() - 1;
        for(index = 0 ; index <= maxlen ; index++)
    {
        eachnumber = number.charAt(index);

        eachnumber = eachnumber  - intConvert;

        reVal = reVal + (eachnumber * (int) Math.pow(10, maxlen - index));
    }
    return reVal;
}
```

Second, for converting `int` to `String`:

```
public static String IntToString(int number)
{
    int StringConvet = 48;

    int eachDigit = number;
    int afterDivide = number;
    String reVal = "";

    while(afterDivide >0)
    {
        eachDigit = afterDivide % 10;
        afterDivide = afterDivide / 10;
        if(eachDigit == 0)
        {
            reVal += "0";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 1)
        {
            reVal += "1";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 2)
        {
            reVal += "2";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 3)
        {
            reVal += "3";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 4)
        {
            reVal += "4";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 5)
        {
            reVal += "5";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 6)
        {
            reVal += "6";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 7)
        {
            reVal += "7";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 8)
        {
            reVal += "8";
        }
        else if(eachDigit == 9)
        {
            reVal += "9";
        }
    }
    String reVal2 = "";
    for(int index =  reVal.length() -1 ; index >= 0 ; index--)
    {
        reVal2 += reVal.charAt(index);
    }
    return reVal2;
}
```

I am sure that the `StringToint` method is \$O(n)\$ and `intToString` method will be \$O(n^2)\$. However, I am really sure that there are ways to improve these two methods. Is there any way to improve these two functions?

Comment: Your making these on purpose right.. Instead of just using Integer.parseInt() and Integer.toString()..

Comment: yep, I am studying about interview questions and I just want to know the better way to build these methods.

Comment: What happens if you need a string representation of a negative number?

Comment: For the love of baby Jesus, fix your indentation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To improve your `intToString()` method you should consider using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and specifically the method [`StringBuilder.append(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28int%29).

Iterate digits in your `int`, and for each digit you can `append(eachDigit)` to the `StringBuilder` element. This will also reduce the complexity of `intToString()` to \$O(n)\$ since you do not need to create a new `String` instance each iteration. To get a `String` object from the `StringBuilder`, use `StringBuilder.toString()`. Or, if you are not allowed, you can use [`StringBuilder.subString(0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring%28int%29).

You should also use a `StringBuilder.append()` (using the same idea) to reverse the resulting string (your second loop in your code).

Since it is not homework (as per comments), I have no problems providing a code snap. It should look something like this:

```
public static String intToString(int n) { 
    if (n == 0) return "0";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (n > 0) { 
        int curr = n % 10;
        n = n/10;
        sb.append(curr);
    }
    String s = sb.substring(0);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.substring(0);
}
```

Notes:

- You can also use [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) instead of the second loop.
- In here, \$O(n)\$ means linear in the the number of digits in the input number (`n` is the number of digits in the input number - not the number itself!) If you are looking for the complexity in terms of the initial number (it is \$O(\log(n))\$) since you divide your element by 10 each iterations, you have a total of \$\log_{10}(\text{number})\$ iterations for each loop, which results in \$O(\log(\text{number}))\$.

Comment: sorry , it is not homework. It actually came from the interview questions. I was preparing the interview for coding questions. Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is still O(n^2) though, you can easily insert at beginning, otherwise there no need to use a StringBuilder (even because javac will optimize it to a StringBuilder in most cases)

Comment: @Jack: No, it is `O(n)` - each loop is `O(n)` - the algorithm is total of `O(2 * n) = O(n)`. inserting element in the beginning will probably make it `O(n^2)` - since inserting an element to the beginning of [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Performance) is `O(n)` each for each insert.

Comment: Yes, yours it still O(2n), misread the code sorry. I was thinking about the internal implementation of StringBuilder, I thought it worked by doing some black magic with linked lists, not a plain internal array. But if it's a dynamic array of course insert will require O(n). I guess that with `Math.ceil(Math.log10(number))` we could be able to avoid reversing the string then.

Answer (score 2):

For your example , I should point out some problems : first , when you add two add string frequently, you should use `StringBuilder` instead ; second , you should consider `Integer.MIN_VALUE` into account!Here is my code:

```
public static String parseInt(int integer)
{
    boolean ifNegative = integer<0;
    boolean ifMin = integer == Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();        
    integer = ifNegative?(ifMin?Integer.MAX_VALUE:-integer):integer;    
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
    int remaining = integer;
    int currentDigit = 0 ;

    while(true)
    {
        currentDigit = remaining%10;
        list.add(currentDigit);
        remaining /= 10;
        if(remaining==0) break;
    }

    currentDigit = list.remove(0);
    builder.append(ifMin?currentDigit+1:currentDigit);
    for(int c : list)
        builder.append(c);
    builder.reverse().insert(0, ifNegative?'-':'+');
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems indeed quite overkill.

Conversion from string to int can be done in a way similar to yours, but by multiplying the result by 10 at every step, without the need to calculate the i-th power for every digit:

```
int stringToInt(String s)
{
  int r = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
  {
    if (i > 0)
      r *= 10;

    r += s.charAt(i)-'0';
  }
  return r;
}
```

While conversion from int to string can take into account the difference between the char `'0'` and the current character of the string without the need of a if/else chain. In addition you can use a string buffer to insert characters at the beginning to avoid the necessity of reversing the string.

```
String intToString(int i)
{
  StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

  while (i != 0)
  {
    b.insert(0, (char)('0'+i%10));
    i /= 10;
  }

  return b.toString();
}
```

Mind that the cast to `char` is needed to avoid using the method `insert(int offset, int value)` that would actually convert the int to a string.

Comment: note that `b.insert()` is `O(n)`. have a look on the performance of [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Performance) [which I *think* this is how `StringBuilder` is implemented]. inserting an element to the beginning is `O(n)` each, so total of `O(n^2)`. Also, there is a special case of `i == 0`, which should be handled.